# Jquery how to visit url + var?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The text in my input is: test

What I want to do is end up with the next result:

some url + var

```
http://google.com/test
```

---

```
function off(){
var visit = $('#visit').val();
window.location = (visit);
}
```

Something like that:

```
window.location = "http://google.com/(visit)";
```

But the var is not acceptable

Comment: concatenation?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function off(){
    var visit = $('#visit').val();
    var url = "https://google.com/"
    window.location = url + visit;
}
```

Simple concatenation where url is what you want the URL to be and visit is whatever you're appending

Comment: i just realised the answer is literally inside the question title... bahaha

Comment: Okay it's funny lol, if I knew it was all because of  + ^^ thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want?

```
window.location = "http://google.com/" + visit;
```